# How to return a tag from a method in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to return a tag from a method so that once I call the method the tags are returned and these tags are used to call a component.

```
const Populate =() =>
{
  let tags = [];
  analysisinfo.forEach((_item,index) =>
  {
   if(analysisinfo[index].id!== defaultid)
    tags.push(<AU props={analysisinfo[index]} instance ={index}/>);
    console.log({tags});
   }
 return tags;
```

let me explain in-detail the analysisinfo is an useState array which contains the below values. These values are being passed into this method.

```
0:
cpu: true
hdd: true
id: "00000000000000000000000000000000"
ram: true
```

And pushes these values into tags[]. I want them pushed into array in the form of a <>, so that  when I return it calls the <AU..../> tag component which takes the above values as props.

Answer (score 0):

Use a combination of `filter` and `map`:

```
const Populate = () => (
    <>
        { 
            analysisinfo
                .filter(i => i.id !== defaultid)
                .map((i, idx) => (
                    <AU props={i} instance={idx} />
                ))
         }
    </>
);
```

Comment: Would be nice if you explain what happens here instead of just giving the answer. :-)

Comment: @JeroenE would be nice, not required. There's 100 questions on here that explain both `Array.filter` and `Array.map` better than I could in this answer. Very basic functions which have been part of ECMAScript since 2009!!!! should not have to be repeated every question, similarly to how we don't explain what a variable or boolean is in every answer.

Comment: @nbokmans On calling the method, this is'nt populating the AU component, what would be the reason?